# Use Last Value in Column for Summary Instead of SUM

Tags: c#, .net, linq, infragistics

I have following code to remove the summary row/band value on a retrieve UI event.  I'm certain this is the wrong way to do it but it works.

```
public UiEventResult AfterRetrieveData_111(object sender, RetrieveDataEventArgs e)
    {
        UltraGridBase baseGrid = _view.ViewGrids["ultraGrid1"];
        UltraGridLayout gridLayout = baseGrid.DisplayLayout;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            gridLayout.Bands[i].Columns["columnA"].Formula = "''";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            gridLayout.Bands[i].Columns["columnB"].Formula = "''";
            gridLayout.Bands[i].Columns["columnC"].Formula = "''";
        }
```

Is there a way to program the retrieve so that it populates the summary row for column A/band[2] so that is uses the last value in each column?  Without the above code it will sum rows under but would like for a way for it to use the last row value instead.  Data will always be sorted DESC by date so last row will always be the value needed...

[image]

Comment: you can use linq LastOrDefault in order to have the last row values. https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop through ChildBands and set parent row value with the last value in each ChildBand.

```
int rowCount = gridLayout.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
foreach (UltraGridChildBand childBand in baseGrid.Rows[i].ChildBands)
     {
      foreach (UltraGridRow row in childBand.Rows)
          {
           row.Cells["columnA"].Value =row.ChildBands.LastRow.Cells["columnA"].Value;
          }
     }
            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is in [InitializeRowEvent](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawingrid%7Einfragistics.win.ultrawingrid.ultragrid%7Einitializerow_ev) by setting the value of the columnA to the value of the last row in the child band like this:

```
// Update the rows only in the first band. You can also use e.Row.Band.Key == {YOU_BAND_KEY}
if (e.Row.Band.Index == 0)
{
    // set the value of the columnA to the value of the last row in the child band
    e.Row.Cells["columnA"].Value = e.Row.ChildBands.LastRow.Cells["columnA"].Value;
}
```

Note, this will not work if you edit the cells values. If you need to update the parent row value after cell update, again in InitializeRowEvent you can add this:

```
// look for row in the secon band
if (e.Row.Band.Index == 1)
{
    // get the last row in the second band
    if (e.Row == e.Row.ParentRow.ChildBands.LastRow)
    {
        // get the value of the last row in the second band and set it to the parent row
        e.Row.ParentRow.Cells["columnA"].Value = e.Row.Cells["columnA"].Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Appears InitializeRowEvent is not available from the client.  Possibly application I am on is older version of Infragistics so it isnt available...??  I have AfterRowActivate but it will not take e.Row.

Comment: InitializeRow event was there even in version 14.1. It should be there in your version too.

Comment: `if(ultraGrid1.Rows.Band.Index == 0)
{
_view.ViewGrids["ultraGrid1"].ActiveRow.Cells["columnA"].Value = _view.ViewGrids["ultraGrid1"].ActiveRow.ChildBands.LastRow.Cells["columnA"].Value;
}`
Above syntax works using AfterRowActivate but user has to physically click on the row.

Comment: Just checked the client is on 14.1.  Not sure why the application doesn't have InitializeRowEvent.  We do have InitView - Or initialize  view but I dont think that will work since the hook occurs before the view has data from what I am reading.

Comment: thanks for your help I was able to get the solution using LastRow